# Visual Studio, .dll not found(never asked for it)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I told Visual Studio the extra library directory and wrote the .lib in the extra dependencies. (Yes, .lib, not .dll). Then all the external symbol files errors were gone(had some of them before), but then comes this:

The actual name and what i said to the additional dependencies was: assimp.lib

But when i run the program, it says: A dependent dll was not found, and in the message box, it says Assimp32.dll

And i have never, ever said to include a dll name, and especially that name, so I'm very confused, and i have checked several times if i made a mistake, but doesn't seem like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have told your application to use the DLL by linking against the lib file. The file you're linking against is not a [static library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) as such. As in, it does not contain all the functionality.

In this case it's an [import library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries) (assimp.lib) which contains the entry point information into the DLL (assimp32.dll). That is why when you run the program, it still asks for a DLL. Even though you might think you have not told your program to do so.

Comment: Thank you for describing this - I was very confused thinking I was providing a static library with assimp.lib, but still seeing "a dependent dll was not found".

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the version 3.0 of the library and I may say that Visual Studio does mean what it says. The size of `assimp.lib` in `assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\lib\assimp_release-dll_win32` is just 88 KB, so it's too small to contain all the code of such extensive library as Open Asset Import Library, while the size of `Assimp32.dll` located in `assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\bin\assimp_release-dll_win32` is whole 6900 KB, so that's where the most goodies are actually located.

Conclusion: `assimp.lib` really does depend on `Assimp32.dll`, so you should copy to and keep `Assimp32.dll` in the same folder where your program's .exe is located.